# Как правильно сделать запрос на сортировку

Tags: php, mysql

Из БД выводится таблица с полями:

```
          <th><?php echo $this->lang->line('id'); ?></th>
          <th><?php echo $this->lang->line('title'); ?></th>
          <th><?php echo $this->lang->line('thumbnail'); ?></th>
          <th><?php echo $this->lang->line('category'); ?></th>
          <th><?php echo $this->lang->line('date_added'); ?></th>
          <th><?php echo $this->lang->line('views'); ?></th>
          <th><?php echo $this->lang->line('status'); ?></th>
          <th><?php echo $this->lang->line('actions'); ?></th>
```

Хочу сделать чтобы по нажатию на ссылку

```
<td><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>videos/categories/<?php echo $video->cat_id; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $video->cat_name; ?></a></td>
```

таблица сортировалась по столбцу  category в БД cat_id

```
т.е. SELECT * FROM  `videos` 
ORDER BY  `videos`.`cat_id` ASC LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Как правильно сделать запрос на сортировку, чтобы в новом окне была таблица с показателями cat_id?

Comment: раскройте, пожалуйста, ваш вопрос, т.к. я не понимаю что вы реально хотите, т.к. ваш запрос SELECT * FROM  `videos` 
ORDER BY  `videos`.`cat_id` ASC LIMIT 0 , 30 прекрасно выберет все показатели cat_id, ну и вообще все, что есть в таблице

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно вы вообще смотрите не в ту сторону. Обычно при необходимости поменять порядок сортировки HTML таблицы, это делается без перезагрузки страницы, при помощи JavaScript.

Вот, например, плагин для jQuery, который помогает это сделать довольно просто
http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Comment: Спасибо. Отличный плагин, закрывает все вопросы...

Answer (score 0):

замените ссылку

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>videos/categories/<?php echo $video->cat_id; ?>
```

на

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>videos/categories/<?php echo $video->cat_id . "?sort=asc"; ?>
```

и запрос

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM  `videos` ORDER BY  `videos`.`cat_id` ASC LIMIT 0 , 30";
```

на

```
$sort ='';
if (isset($_GET['sort'])) { $sort = 'ORDER BY videos.cat_id ASC';   }
$query =  "SELECT * FROM  `videos` $sort LIMIT 0 , 30";
```

Comment: Не выводит столбец category (cat_id) из БД - вообще... Следующие столбцы просто сдвинулись на место category.  Сделал пока так:`<td><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>videos/category/mypage.php?sort=cat_id" target="_blank"><?php echo $video->cat_name; ?></a></td>                                                 $sql = "SELECT * FROM videos";
if ($_GET['sort'] == 'cat_id')
{
    $sql .= " ORDER BY cat_id";`